# Digikam is not launching Nautilus from context menu "open in File Manager"

Tags: gnome, 22.04, nautilus, digikam

Nautilus is no longer responding to the context menu of Digikam on Ubuntu 22.04 to an image selected and the right click context menu "Open in file manager" Feature in Shotwell still works. Is there a setting in Nautilus or Gnome to fix this?